# __stdcall typedef g++ problem

Tags: c++, windows, g++, stdcall

This code compiles (as I would expect):

```
typedef void __stdcall (*Func)();

struct A {
    static void __stdcall f() { }
};

int main() {
    Func p = A::f;
}
```

But this one:

```
struct A {
    typedef void __stdcall (*Func)();
    static void __stdcall f() { }
};

int main() {
    A::Func p = A::f;
}
```

fails with not-very-helpful error message:

```
error: invalid conversion from `void (*)()' to `void (*)()'
```

I'm using g++ 3.4.2 under Vista (I know, it's ancient, but I don't have access to any other environment right now). Obviously I am missing something here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. In C ot is common to get the address of a function. in C++ it is very rare to need the address of a function or method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax is `void(__stdcall *)()`, not `void __stdcall (*)()`.

Comment: That was a simple answer. Thank you!