# Template partial specialization for __stdcall function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, stdcall

```
typedef bool (*my_function_f)(int, double);
typedef bool (__stdcall *my_function_f2)(int, double);
//            ^^^^^^^^^

template<class F> class TFunction;

template<class R, class T0, class T1>
class TFunction<R(*)(T0,T1)>
{
  typedef R (*func_type)(T0,T1);
};

int main()
{
  TFunction<my_function_f> t1;  // works on x64 and win32
  TFunction<my_function_f2> t2; // works on x64 and doesn't work on win32

  return 0;
}
```

The code above gives me the following error in Visual C++ 2010:

```
1>e:\project\orwell\head\multimapwizard\trunk\externals.cpp(49): error C2079: 't2' uses undefined class 'Externals::TFunction<F>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=Externals::my_function_f2
1>          ]
```

As you can see the problem with `__stdcall` modifier. Is this the compiler bug?

Comment: [__stdcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx): "On Itanium Processor Family (IPF) and x64 processors, __stdcall is accepted and ignored by the compiler", which I guess is why it works 64-bit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534907/stdcall-typedef-g-problem might help

Comment: @sehe isn't he already using that syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is by design.  The calling convention is very much part of the function declaration, your template function uses the default calling convention.  Which is not __stdcall unless you compile with /Gz.  The default is /Gd, __cdecl.

The code compiles when you target x64 because it blissfully has only one calling convention.

Fix:

```
template<class R, class T0, class T1>
class TFunction<R (__stdcall *)(T0,T1)>
{
    // etc..
};
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because (*) means default calling convention, which is `__cdecl`.

```
template<class R, class T0, class T1>
class TFunction<R(*)(T0,T1)>
{
  typedef R (*func_type)(T0,T1);
};
```

is actually equal to

```
template<class R, class T0, class T1>
class TFunction<R(__cdecl *)(T0,T1)>
{
  typedef R (__cdecl *func_type)(T0,T1);
};
```

which, of course, will not match an `R(__stdcall *)(T0, T1)` on Win32 where `__stdcall` is not ignored. If you want to partially specialize for function pointers then you will need a partial spec for every calling convention you want to accept.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specialized your template for the stdcall case, i.e. you need

```
template<class R, class T0, class T1>
class TFunction<R(__stdcall *)(T0,T1)>
{
  typedef R (*func_type)(T0,T1);
};
```

Not sure about the syntax, untested, but that should be the issue.