# Why won't this template compile?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class used with MSVC2013 Update 4:

```
template <typename T>
class MyFunction;

template<typename R, class... Ts>
class MyFunction < R(Ts...) >
{
public:
    using func_type = R(*)(Ts...);

    MyFunction(func_type f)
        : m_func(f)
    {
    }

    R operator()(Ts ... args)
    {
        return m_func(args...);
    }

private:
    func_type m_func;
};
```

If I use it like so:

```
MyFunction<int (int)> f1(nullptr);
MyFunction<int __cdecl(int)> f2(nullptr);
MyFunction<int __stdcall(int)> f3(nullptr);
```

Why does f3 fail to compile? (Considering that __cdecl works!).

```
error C2079: 'f3' uses undefined class 'MyFunction<int (int)>'  
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'nullptr' to 'int'
```

Comment: `nullptr != NULL`. Think about it.

Comment: The constructor takes a func_type, which is a function pointer, thus nullptr is fine?

Comment: I suspect that `R(Ts...)` is implicitly `R __cdecl (Ts...)`, so that partial specialization doesn't match `int __stdcall(int)`.

Comment: Also note that f1 and f2 do compile, only f3 has an issue

Comment: @T.C. if so would there be some way to pass the calling convention in?

Comment: Write partial specializations for all calling conventions you care about. You may want to derive from an common base template.

Comment: @T.C. I have no idea how that would look :(

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991507/template-partial-specialization-for-stdcall-function-pointer

Comment: Don't forget perfect forwarding

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot what do you mean? I should be using std::forward in operator()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MSVC, the calling convention is part of the function type; the default calling convention is `__cdecl`, so `R(Ts...)` is really `R __cdecl (Ts...)` and doesn't match `int __stdcall(int)`.

If you compile with `/Gz`, which makes the default calling convention `__stdcall`, you'd see an error on `f2` instead.

You'll have to write partial specializations for all calling conventions you want to support:

```
template<class F, class R, class... Args>
class MyFunctionImpl {
public:
    using func_type = F*;

    MyFunctionImpl(func_type f)
        : m_func(f)
    {
    }

    R operator()(Args ... args)
    {
        return m_func(args...);
    }

private:
    func_type m_func;
};

template<typename R, class... Ts>
class MyFunction < R __cdecl(Ts...) >
    : MyFunctionImpl<R __cdecl(Ts...), R, Ts...> {
    using MyFunctionImpl<R __cdecl(Ts...), R, Ts...>::MyFunctionImpl;
};

template<typename R, class... Ts>
class MyFunction < R __stdcall(Ts...) >
    : MyFunctionImpl<R __stdcall(Ts...), R, Ts...> {
    using MyFunctionImpl<R __stdcall(Ts...), R, Ts...>::MyFunctionImpl;
};

// etc.
```